# Set DialogFragment size in XML layout

Tags: android, layout, dialogfragment

I am looking for a way to set the size of a DialogFragment in the XML layout. I know I could set it in the code in the onResume() method, but that is not what I want. Does anyone know how I could do that?

I realize that there are some similar questions here on SO, but none of them has a satisfying answer.

The layout looks somewhat like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp" >

    ...
```

And the this is the DialogFragment code:

```
public class MyTestDialog extends DialogFragment {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onResume()
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // just to see the dialog bounds
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_blue);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```